# ¿Cómo hago para guardar un array de objeto json en localstorage?

Tags: javascript, web, local-storage

El código es el siguiente:

```
var usuarios = [
    { nombre: 'kevin44', pass: '44', email: 'aaa@gmail', deposito: 5000 },
    { nombre: 'kevin33', pass: '33', email: 'bbb@gmail', deposito: 0 },
    { nombre: 'kevin22', pass: '22', email: 'ccc@gmail', deposito: 1000 },
    { nombre: 'kevin11', pass: '11', email: 'ddd@gmail', deposito: 3000 },
];

localStorage.setItem('usuario', JSON.stringify(usuarios));

for (var i in persona) {
    console.log(usuarios[i].email);
}
var persona;
persona = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('usuario'));
console.log(persona[3]);
```

El problema es que cuando quiero incrustarlos en el **HTML** me tira [object object] y la idea es que me haga una lista de los usuarios, ¡pero no doy pie con bola!

```
for (var i in usuarios) {

            var li = document.createElement('li');
            li.append(persona[i]);
            ul.append(li);
        }
```

Comment: Si te tira [Object Object] es porque estas intentando agregar al objeto entero a tu HTML, la solución es realmente sencilla, tanto que yo creo que caerás en cuenta en que estas haciendo mal tu mismo rápidamente, si no es así dejare que otro miembro te de la solución o esperar un rato para darte la miá, siempre es bueno dejar pensar un rato al usuario para ver si el mismo puede resolver el problema, pero pues... viendo que la mayoria de vecez ninguno espera esto posiblemente en unos 10 o 20 minutos obtengas 2 o 3 respuestas.

Comment: Ahhh una cosa mas, aquí en este sitio puedes incluso responder a tu propia pregunta si hallaste la solución (avecez los usuarios lo hacen).

Comment: Por cierto bienvenido a la comunidad @Kevin Cánepa, me sorprende que tu primera pregunta sea una pregunta valida y bien formateada, normalmente las preguntas de los nuevos en el sitio tendemos a tener que recomendarle como formular una buena pregunta... sin embargo (aunque no sea el caso), si tienes curiosidad puedes ir por el [tour] y leer sobre [ask], aunque en tu caso esta pregunta es completamente valida felicidades.

Comment: Ya esta!! lo solucione!! estaba tratando de imprimir el objeto completo de una. No sabia que no se podia! le puse para imprimir una propiedad(nombre) y me salio bien. Gracias!

Comment: De nada Kevin, si, era algo muy sencillo, debido a que lo solucionaste tu te recomiendo que pongas la solución (respuesta) que tuviste a tu pregunta en la caja de respuestas (recuerda que puedes hacerlo), y en 2 días podrás dar tu pregunta como aceptada.

Comment: Como respondo con codigo? porque trato de darle formato como se lo di en la pregunta pero no me lo toma!

Comment: Hay un simbolo de llaves {} dentro de la caja de respuestas, aquel texto que quieras que sea codigo lo seleccionas y le das click a las llaves, automaticamente se formateara a código.

Comment: En general si puedes imprimir objetos con `console.log`, tienes que estar seguro que no estes concatenando algún string al objeto, si lo haces te saldrá lo de `[object Object]`