# ¿Cómo puedo guardar en un json los elementos de una lista? javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente HTML.
Dos listas diferentes y dentro de cada lista diferentes párrafos
Necesito guardar los párrafos de diferentes litas en json diferentes , uno para cada lista:

```
<ul id="listaNombre">
      <li>
        <p>Jorge</p>
        <p>Juan</p>
        <p>Pepe</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Mar</p>
        <p>Nerea</p>
        <p>Julia</p>
      </li>
</ul>

<ul id="listaCiudades">
      <li>
        <p>Barcelona</p>
        <p>Alicante</p>
        <p>Valencia</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Elche</p>
        <p>Madrid</p>
        <p>Zaragoza</p>
      </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Pon lo que has intentado o trabajado

Comment: Te recomiendo esta pregunta solucionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/352663/155688. Si aún no te ayuda, muestra tu trabajo completo

Comment: Tu pregunta no es muy clara... reformulala e incluye que has intentado